# Complex integral in spectrum estimator

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, complex-integration

I've been studying Fourier analysis of time series and in order to find an unbiased and consistent estimator for the spectrum, Barlett proposed a solution in 1953, the so called "smooth covariances estimator".

Problem is, for this estimator, there are some complex integrals with which I am not totally familiar yet. I am having trouble understanding a setp from the book. It says that:

$$ W(\lambda) = \int_{\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i\lambda \tau} \left(1 - \frac{|\tau|}{T}\right)d\tau $$

is the Fourier transform of this function $w(\tau) = 1 - |\tau|/T$, for $|\tau| \leq T $. Now the book states that:

$$ W(\lambda) = T\left[ \frac{sin(\pi T \lambda)}{\pi T \lambda}\right]^2 $$

and I cant figure out how I can get there. Can you guys give me any advice? Thanks!

## EDIT

Trying to evaluate the integral, I have:

$$ \int_{-T}^{T}e^{-i\lambda \tau}(1-\frac{|\tau|}{T})d\tau =  \int_{-T}^{T}e^{-i\lambda \tau}d\tau - \frac{1}{T} \int_{-T}^{T} |\tau|e^{-i\lambda \tau}d\tau $$

Now what I get is that:

$$ \int_{-T}^{T} e^{-i\lambda \tau}d\tau = \frac{e^{i\lambda T} - e^{-i\lambda T}}{i\lambda} = 2\frac{sin(\lambda T)}{\lambda T}$$ which seems quite reasonable.

Breaking piecewise $\frac{1}{T} \int_{-T}^{T} |\tau|e^{-i\lambda \tau}d\tau $:

$$\frac{1}{T} \int_{-T}^{T} |\tau|e^{-i\lambda \tau}d\tau = \frac{1}{T} \int_{0}^{T} \tau e^{-i\lambda \tau}d\tau - \frac{1}{T} \int_{-T}^{0} \tau e^{-i\lambda \tau}d\tau  $$

Since:

$$\frac{1}{T} \int \tau e^{-i\lambda \tau}d\tau = \frac{e^{-i\lambda \tau}(1+i\lambda \tau)}{\lambda^2 T}  $$

The resulting integral is:

$$ \frac{1}{T} \int_{-T}^{T} |\tau|e^{-i\lambda \tau}d\tau = \frac{2(\lambda T sin(\lambda T) + cos(\lambda T)-1)}{T \lambda^2 } $$

Computing both integrals together, still my result doesn't match what I expected. Where am I mistaken?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem quite correct. The bounds for the integration should only be $[-T,T]$, or the function be written piecewise so it is $0$ everywhere else outside that interval. This uses the the convolution to product property of Fourier transforms. $w$ is the convolution of a rectangle function with itself. The FT of a rectangle is a sinc. Then $\mathcal{F}(h\star h) = \mathcal{F}(h)\cdot\mathcal{F}(h)$

Comment: The function $ w(\tau) $ is defined only in $ [-T, T]$. I corrected it. But I am having trouble computing the integral itself.

Comment: You don't have to compute it directly, you only have to use the Fourier Transform properties I listed.

Comment: If you want to compute it directly, then split up the absolute value into a piecewise function, do two separate integration by parts to leave you with an expression with complex exponentials. From there, use Euler's formula.

Comment: My problem was computing it direclty. I didn't use the properties before because it's my first contact with Fourier analysis, so I didn't know yhem. But I will try it now! Thank you for your tips!

Comment: Several problems. One the integral of an odd function would be $0$, not an even function. Second that function is neither even nor odd. I told you to split up the absolute value piecewise.

Comment: @NinadMunshi edited again. You've been quite helpful